# How to create a read-only user for NEO4J 2.2

Tags: neo4j

Now I want to create a read-only user who can login the web browser and webadmin without the permission to modify the graph.
  I know there is **read-only mode** , but this will get the instance read-only, not very convenient for my bussiness requirement.

My question is :

1,if there is a configuration to add a  read-only user, how can I do this? I didn`t find this in documentation.
  2,If there is not, I would like to create a customized configuration for this, and where should I find the file store user,passowrd or authorization token?

Could you give some suggestions? Any answer is appriciated!

Comment: For all read-only databases you can set `read_only=true` in `conf/neo4j.properties`

Answer (score 2):

The new user authorization feature doesn't provide roles or different access levels. At the moment it's "all or nothing". Upcoming versions of Neo4j will most likely have some role based concept aboard.

In the meantime you can implement [SecurityRules](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M01/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules) on your own. SecurityRules are acting like servlet filter and allow vetoing the execution of a certain incoming http request.